# transition Instagram app/client from one user to another

Tags: instagram

We recently built a web site for a customer, and a feature of the site imported data from Instagram.  We registered an Instagram "client" on behalf of our customer in order to use the Instagram API.

Now that the site is built and in maintenance mode, we would like to hand our customer the keys so to speak.  With Facebook apps I can add developers as admins to an app then remove ourselves.  However, how do I transition an Instagram client from one Instagram user to another?

Thanks in advance.